# DNS error in android 4.4.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4, dns

I just get an new mobile Samsung Galaxy S4 GT-I9505 with Android 4.4.2.

When I try to connect to internet through 3G/4G network, my Chrome always give me an error message:

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

The internet can be accessed by IP address with the same network.

How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved as I install avast firewall and need to enable linux shell to access mobile data.